# Django Project Setup on Google VM

Tags: python, django, nginx, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am trying to setup a django project on a VM by Google Compute Engine. I have done all the installations & have copied the project on my VM. But I am not able to do the Apache/mod_wsgi Or Gunicorn/Nginx linking to make the project run end to end on the final IP address of VM.

I have two queries:

1) Which one is better Apache/mod_wsgi OR Gunicorn/Nginx OR any other ?

2) Can someone please explain in simple step by step way to do this linking?

Any one way Or some good Reference Link would also be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Add the Following Code in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf File.
Do make corresponding changes acc. to your project path.

1) sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

2) Add below code between  &

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    . . .

    Alias /static /home/user/myproject/static
    <Directory /home/user/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/user/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/user/myproject:/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

3) sudo chown :www-data ~/myproject/

4) sudo service apache2 restart

Now try hitting your IP address. Enjoy!

Hope this might be helpful.

Thanks,